# QTreeWidgetItem find child by text

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidgetitem

How to find item in QTreeWidgetItem by text? Is there an analog of QTreeWidget's findItem method ?

Comment: Do you mean find item in the list of children of QTreeWidgetItem  ?

Comment: @Ashot, yes, I want to find item by text

Comment: Seems like there is not analog method in QTreeWidgetItem. Anyway you can iterate over the children of item and find out what have text you want.

Comment: @Ashot, I decided to do just that. Thanks for answer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is recursive search in a QTreeWidget. For that you will have to use the combination of `Qt::MatchContains | Qt::MatchRecursive` as flag.

So if pMyTreeWidget is the pointer to your `QTreeWidget` and myText is the `QString` containing the text you want to search, assuming that the search has to be on column 0, the code will look something like:

```
QList<QTreeWidgetItem*> clist = pMyTreeWidget->findItems(myText, Qt::MatchContains|Qt::MatchRecursive, 0);
foreach(QTreeWidgetItem* item, clist)
{
    qDebug() << item->text(0);
}
```

If your requirement is to match the exact text, then you can use `Qt::MatchExactly|Qt::MatchRecursive` instead of `Qt::MatchContains|Qt::MatchRecursive`